# How To Solve TypeScript Error 7053 in React Form handleChange function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a generic `handleChange` function in a react form. The handleChange function will update the state value whenever a form field is updated. I'd like function to be able to handle nested values. Here is my attempt:

```
  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
        
    if(!name.includes('.')){
      return setFormValue((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }))
    }
    const [prop, key] = value
    
    return setFormValue((prevState) => {
      const nested= prevState[prop] // TS ERROR HERE
      nested[key] = value;
      return ({
        ...prevState,
        ...nested
      })
    })
  }
```

This works however typescript is throwing an error. Here is the TS error thrown on the line that is commented:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'Form'. No index signature with
> a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Form'.ts(7053)

I've been researching this error for a while but with everything I searched, I can't crack it.

Here is what the Form's data looks like:

```
interface Form {
  name: string  
  contactNumber: string
  address: Address
  category: string
}

interface Address {
  postCode: string
  country: string
  city: string
  name: string
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I can solve this TS error?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is complaining because it understands that `name` is a `string`.
At the same time, your Form interface has some specific keys (`name`, `contactNumber`, and ...). TypeScript could not make sure that `e.target.name` is necessarily equal to one of the valid keys. In case you're always sure that `e.target.name` is a valid Form property, you can assure TypeScript using `as` keyword:

```
[name as keyof Form]: value
```

Comment: Thanks @kavian! That explanation makes a lot of sense. Where would I insert that in the handleChange function? I'm not that familiar with that syntax, I tried putting it on line3 in the code posted above but received errors. Do you have any suggestions on where to place it?

Comment: I assume you need it to be defined inside a component's body.

Comment: If the original answer helped, please consider to mark it as rhe correcr answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still trying to get it to work :), I'll mark it as the answer after I can apply it to my problem, thanks again!